# Bugged flame appears only middle of the domain

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I don't know what happened but my flame suddenly broke. İt was very good and detailed. I don't know what ı changed. Flame appears only in middle of the domain with very bad resolution. Also when ı try to increase division program crashing. Before these events start ı can increase it very beyond from the point now. All related object's scales are 1.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share your simplified file (like without rocket) just part of scene that produce the issue. Use https://blend-exchange.com/ and copy paste given code into your Q. Thanks

Comment: I added the blend file. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: When I asked to simplify your file I wanted to let you delete those objects not hide from viewport ... file is than smaller to share and it is easier for us to understand your project structure.

Comment: I thought I deleted it but my brain automatically pressed h instead of del i think. I uploaded correctly again. Thanks for your answer problem solved and ı learned a new thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set under *Object Data Properties* > *Texture Space > Size* **X1 Y1 Z1**, that is not correspond to your domain ...

[image]

... but it should be half of Object Dimension (size is measured from object origin, so if your object is X10, than Texture Space is X5) ... or more efficient enable **Auto Texture Space**

[image]

[image]